# How write jQuery selector for numeric list elements without link

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have to write a specific selector in jQuery it has to choose all elements in numeric list (with given class "a") which has class "b" and no links inside. And them give them certain class(which give them certain formatting).

So for example for such list:

```
<ol class="a">
    <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">List element</a></li>
    <li class="b"><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">List element</a></div></li>
    <li class="b">List element</a></li>
</ol>
```

Only the last element should get that class.

Though when I tried to do it like this:

```
$('ol.a li.b:not(a)').addClass('someclass');
```

then the second element gets that class too.

I also tried to do this with space before ":not(a)", but this way nothing get that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? I think I understood what you were asking. Please let me know if it's not so I can amend my answer. :)

Essentially `'ol.a li.b:not(:has(a))'` means to search for an ordered list with a class of `a`, with any descendent `li` item with a class of `b` that *doesn't* have *any* children that are an anchor `a`.

```js
const nonLinks = $('ol.a li.b:not(:has(a))');

nonLinks.addClass("red");
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="a">
        <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">First</a></li>
        <li class="b"><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Second Element</a></li>
        <li class="b">Shouldn't Be Included</li>
</ol>
```